# Why sqs v3 php sdk receive_message MaxNumberOfMessages=10 does not return 10 messages?

Tags: php, amazon-sqs

I am retrieving message from a queue created through amazon sqs.  There are around 6 messages in my queue.  But I can able to retrieve only one message each time.  In document they mentioned you can retrieve up to 10 messages.  But I am not getting more than one message at a time.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-sqs-2012-11-05.html#receivemessage

Here I am setting MaxNumberOfMessages=10 but still I am getting only one message.

Can anyone help me to retrieve all messages?

Comment: If I am not wrong you are using RecieveMessage ?

Comment: IMHO, just loop and read the message until empty.

Comment: @naresh ..yeah i am using receive message...@mootmoot ..I am getting only one message then how can i loop?

Answer (score 1):

Could be because of this:

> If the number of messages in the queue is small (less than 1000), it is likely you will get fewer messages than you requested per ReceiveMessage call. If the number of messages in the queue is extremely small, you might not receive any messages in a particular ReceiveMessage response; in which case you should repeat the request.